# How can I prevent gdb *input/output* buffer from aggressively popping up in frame?

Tags: window, frames, gud, gdb

When using gdb with `M-x gdb`, the `*input/output*` buffer always pops up aggressively in any frame which has focus and isn't already displaying it. I would like the `*input/output*` buffer to stay quietly in the background unless I manually bring it up.

Here's a very simple example with `emacs -Q`

run `M-x gdb`. give a program of `bash` and hit `Return`

in the `*gud-bash*` window, enter `run -c "while true; do echo hi && sleep 1; done"`

Notice how the `*input/output of bash*` window pops up. If you dismiss that buffer with `C-x 1` from the `*gud-bash*` window, it comes back as soon as gdb produces any more stdout. That's the behavior I don't want.

In particular, now run `M-x make-frame` (from the `*gud-bash*` window). Notice how in the new frame, `*input/output of bash*` also pops up! So it demands one window out of every single emacs frame.

How can I fix this?

Edit: I almost forgot to add - emacs version of

`GNU Emacs 24.5.2 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.30)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As soon as emacs 25 lands, there will be a variable `gdb-display-io-nopopup` to fix this problem

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  This has been an irritation for me for years! This solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

split emacs window into three (c-x 3), and assign one window to the *input/output* buffer (c-x b, *input/output*)

Stops the popup, and program output is displayed in the "*input/output*" buffer window

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "screen", and by "assign".  Also I'm not sure it addresses the issue that the debugger code forces you to have the *input/output* buffer displayed in a window in each frame.

Comment: split emacs windows: (c-x n), assign buffer to a window (c-x b)